# Subscriber not assigned on Observable create

Tags: angular, events, rxjs, observable

I am doing this in code in order to handle multiple views from multiple components

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy8jza
 (check the console for the error)

```
export class ViewGroup {
    _onViewChanged: any;
    OnViewChanged$ : Observable<any>;
    _onViewAdded: any;
    OnViewAdded$ : Observable<any>;
    _onViewRemoved: any;
    OnViewRemoved$ : Observable<any>;

    viewsSet = new Set<string>();
    currentView = "";
    previousView = "";

    constructor(){
    this.OnViewChanged$ = Observable.create(obs => this._onViewChanged = obs);
    this.OnViewAdded$ = Observable.create(obs => this._onViewAdded = obs);
    this.OnViewRemoved$ = Observable.create(obs => this._onViewRemoved = obs);
}
}
```

somnwhere in the code I do

```
this._availableView.set(name,  new ViewGroup());
```

and then call

```
this._availableView.get(group)._onViewAdded.next(view);
```

but I can't call the next on it, it s say undefined.

It's exactly the same procedure has

```
this.onGroupAdded$ = Observable.create(e => this._onGroupAdded = e)
```

but this one work in stackblitz.

**EDIT :** I found out that the method I pass inside the create is not called until I subscribe to it. I have to do this to make everything works :

```
this.OnViewChanged$ = Observable.create((obs) => {this._onViewAdded = obs});
this.OnViewAdded$ = Observable.create((obs) => {this._onViewAdded = obs});
this.OnViewRemoved$ = Observable.create((obs) => {this._onViewAdded = obs});
this.OnViewChanged$.subscribe();
this.OnViewAdded$.subscribe();
this.OnViewRemoved$.subscribe();
```

Is there any way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your case correctly, I think what you are looking for is a subject.

You are correct that observables don't run until they get subscribed to. You can find many references to that in all sorts of docs, for example: [angular docs for observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables#observables).

So instead of creating the observables using the create method. Try declaring them as subjects. Check out how they are being used in angular docs here for more details: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

Comment: I went over this documentation, but I think I interpreted it wrongly, because I reimplemented everything and it work like charm... I closed the other post, cause yo usolve booth problem with this.

thank you !